# Form Still Submitting

Tags: javascript

I am trying to stop a form from being submitted but even though the alert is triggered, the form is still submitting. This is my Javascript code (reduced to essentials):

```
        if(status == 1) {
            alert("Test");
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var elem = document.getElementById("error");
            if(elem) {
                elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            }
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.className = "error_class";
            span.id = "error";
            span.innerHTML = "Please try again.";
            document.getElementById("field").appendChild(span);
            return false;
        }
```

I'm testing with Firefox Beta and Google Chrome Beta. Can someone tell me what's missing? The code above is part of a function assigned to an event listener of a button.

Comment: How is this event listener attached and to *what* event?

Comment: I attached the event using addEventListener and assigned it to the click event of the button.

Comment: Post the actual handler and the relevant html.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @Tim, No, no output.

Comment: You see the alert, so that segment is being called. What if you comment out the next two lines and leave return false?

Comment: @Tim, yes I get the alert.

Comment: I really think we need to see more of the method to help you out. Could you post more code?

Comment: So, this event is attached to the `click` handler on the *submit* button of the form, correct?  If you remove the `alert()` does it function how you want?  (Use `console.log` rather than `alert` when debugging)

Comment: Yes, correct. No difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JasonK's answer, I did some additional research and found the solution. I'm posting the new code doing the same thing as the previous one:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
if(status == 1) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("error");
    if(elem) {
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.className = "error_class";
    span.id = "error";
    span.innerHTML = "Please try again.";
    document.getElementById("field").appendChild(span);
    return false;
}else{
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

In this code, the main difference is that I'm calling e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() at the top of the function as soon as the event is called. Then, I'm using the submit() method so that if status is not 1, the form is still submitted. I hope I'm explaining enough and this might help others since it's my first answer here.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do your stuff
    alert('Form was not submitted!');
});
```

Or you could attach a onclick listener to the submit button

```
$('form .submit-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do your stuff
    alert('Form was not submitted!');
});
```

Hope this helps. If not, show us more code and use the console to check for errors.

Comment: Can you give me a standard Javascript way, please?

Comment: There's no mention of jQuery being used in the question.

Comment: Yes I see now, long day at work. Simply replace `e.preventDefault()` with `return false`, it is really that simple as far as I know.